# Url leading to google search in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: url, firefox

For example I have this localhost folder:

```
http://localhost/Online Buddy/
```

Why doesn't Firefox automatically converts the space between `online` and `buddy` into `%20` like Google Chrome does it? It takes me to the Google Search whenever I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will only replace spaces when it recognises you typing an address. Firefox doesn't automatically recognise localhost as a domain the same way it recognises *.com (etc), apparently, so it assumes you want to search. Your basic options are:

- Don't have any spaces in your site URLs, underscores work Manually
- Put %20 instead of spaces when typing the URL in
- Disable address bar searching

To disable address bar searching, navigate to about:config and set keyword.enabled to false.